# Difference in calling a constructor with delegation, and in another constructor body

Tags: c++, constructor

lets say I have a class with 2 constructors like so:

```
class Foo 
{
    Foo(int x);
    Foo();
    ...
}
```

I know that I can call one constructor from another like `Foo() : Foo(42) {}`, but why shouldn't (or should) I do the following:

```
Foo() {
    Foo(42)
}
```

What is the difference in these cases? 
Some suggest to use an "initializer" method, called from any constructor with their respective arguments, but I am puzzled as to what happens in the case above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
private:
    int number;
public:
    B()
    {
        B(1);
    }

    B(int x) : number(x)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor: " << x << std::endl;
    }

    void print(){
        std::cout << "Msg: " << number << std::endl;
    }

    ~B(){std::cout << "Destructor: " << number << std::endl;}
};


int main() {
    B b;
    b.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Constructor: 1
>   Destructor: 1
>   Msg: 1
>   Destructor: 1

You are destroying a second object! This is strange, what happens if we use pointers...

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
private:
    int* arr;
public:
    B()
    {
        B(1);
    }

    B(int x)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor: " << x << std::endl;
        arr = new int[x];
    }

    void print(int n){
        std::cout << "Msg: " << arr[n] << std::endl;
    }

    void set(int n,int val){
        arr[n] = val;
    }

    ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor: " << arr << std::endl;
        delete[] arr;
    }
};


int main() {
    B b;
    b.set(0,14);
    b.print(0);
    return 0;
}
```

> Constructor: 1
>   Destructor: 0xc45480
>   Msg: 14
>   Destructor: 0xc45480

Look up the pointer addr. They are the same, this means:

- We are writing in deleted memory.
- We are deleting the same memory twice.

These are two serious problems. You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Expression `Foo(){Foo(42);}` constructs anonymous temporary object that gets destroyed immediately without changing the object being constructed anyhow, while from `Foo() : Foo(42){}` will initialize the object being constructed.

Answer (score 1):

You *should not* the following:

```
Foo() {
    Foo(42)
}
```

When you are in the constructor body the member variables have been just constructed. That's why in C++ *initialisation list* exists.

The above code is *semantically* wrong! You are not absolutely using
delegating construction. Instead the statement `Foo(42)` in the body will just create *another* object without assigning it to any variable (*anonymous variable*).

You can imagine something like:

```
Foo() {
  Foo another_obj = Foo(42);
}
```

In order to use delegating constructor, you must call constructor
in the initialisation list.

```
Foo() : Foo(42) { }
```